# How to solve TkTreeCtrl error in Windows?

Tags: python, tkinter

I installed tktreectrl. I successfully imported it too. But, I'm still getting error while executing below program. Someone can help ?

Here's my code...

```
from Tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import TkTreectrl as treectrl

root = Tk()
con = sqlite3.connect('Main.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Lucky")

mlb = treectrl.MultiListbox(root)
mlb.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
Button(root, text='Close', command=root.quit).pack(side='top', pady=5)

mlb.focus_set()   
mlb.configure(selectcmd=select_cmd, selectmode='extended')
mlb.config(columns=('Column 1', 'Column 2'))

for row in cur.fetchall():
    mlb.insert('end',*map(unicode,row))


root.mainloop()
```

Here's my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\Python Work\Cx_Freeze\Multi_litbox.py", line 11, in <module>
    mlb = treectrl.MultiListbox(root)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\TkTreectrl\MultiListbox.py", line 50, in __init__
    Treectrl.__init__(self, master, showroot=showroot, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\TkTreectrl\Treectrl.py", line 489, in __init__
    ver = master.tk.call('package', 'require', 'treectrl')
TclError: can't find package treectrl
```

someone plz help me to solve this, I need to use multiple list box in my code?

Comment: I don't know about tktreectrl, but it looks like you are defining root as an empty tuple.  Try fixing that and see what you get.

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. I mistyped it. I just edited it.

Comment: It looks like an installation error to me ... I'd probably try playing with it interactively to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: If you find something useful, please share it.

Comment: If you don't need all the features of tktreectrl (and there's a bunch you probably don't need), you might consider trying the ttk.Treeview widget which doesn't have any external dependencies. See http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html

Comment: Ha, Bryan Oakley, waiting for your comment. Thanks for suggestion. Viewing your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you installed tktreectrl. As you are using Tkinter with python and no plane tcl, you still need the tkintertreectrl installed.

Did you install both packages like Michael hints to on the homepage?

Make sure when installing both to first have the tktreectrl installed.
When building TkinterTreectrl or installing it, try a plain import or creation of a TkinterTreectrl Widget without any data in it.

Looks like a missing tktreectrl installation to me.

**EDIT**: It is a missing tktreectrl installation as you can see in the traceback - TkTreectrl requires 'treectrl' which is currently not available on your system. You can receive it as a package on most debian derivates or directly download it from their [sourceforge page](http://tktreectrl.sourceforge.net/).

Also read through the [notes](http://tkintertreectrl.sourceforge.net/) of Michael on using TkTreectrl

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\TkTreectrl\Treectrl.py", line 489, in __init__
ver = master.tk.call('package', 'require', 'treectrl')
```

TclError: can't find package treectrl

Answer (score 0):

Download 64 or x86 bit tktreectrl (depending upon system arch) from this below link :

https://sourceforge.net/projects/tktreectrl/files/tktreectrl/tktreectrl-2.4.1/

Put it in tcl folder (e.g your conda directory where you get this error --

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\tcl\)`

You will get rid of two types of of error:

Can't find package error
Invalid argument Error